# convert list of lists to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

how can I create a list of dictionaries with those lists

```
temp = [['header1', '4', '8', '16', '32', '64', '128', '256', '512', '243,6'], ['media_range', '1,200', '2,400', '4,800', '4,800', '6,200', '38,400', '76,800', '153,600', '160,000'], ['speed', '300', '600', '1,200', '2,000', '2,000', '2,000', '2,000', '2,000', '2,000']]
```

the headers of the dictionary is the first element of the lists

the expected Output is:

```
output= [{'header1': '4', 'media_range': '1,200', 'speed': '300'}, {'header1': '8', 'media_range': '2,400', 'speed': '600'}, ...]
```

Ideally the code should handle any amount of lists (in this case 3)

Comment: do the lists in temp always have the same lenght?

Comment: @timgeb great question, yes they do but not always 10 (as in question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC

```
>>> temp = [['header1', '4', '8', '16', '32', '64', '128', '256', '512', '243,6'], ['media_range', '1,200', '2,400', '4,800', '4
...: ,800', '6,200', '38,400', '76,800', '153,600', '160,000'], ['speed', '300', '600', '1,200', '2,000', '2,000', '2,000', '2,0
...: 00', '2,000', '2,000']]                                                                                                    
>>>                                                                                                                             
>>> keys = [l[0] for l in temp]                                                                                                 
>>> values = [l[1:] for l in temp]                                                                                              
>>> dicts = [dict(zip(keys, sub)) for sub in zip(*values)]                                                                                                             
>>>                                                                                                                                                                    
>>> dicts                                                                                                                                                              
[{'header1': '4', 'media_range': '1,200', 'speed': '300'},
 {'header1': '8', 'media_range': '2,400', 'speed': '600'},
 {'header1': '16', 'media_range': '4,800', 'speed': '1,200'},
 {'header1': '32', 'media_range': '4,800', 'speed': '2,000'},
 {'header1': '64', 'media_range': '6,200', 'speed': '2,000'},
 {'header1': '128', 'media_range': '38,400', 'speed': '2,000'},
 {'header1': '256', 'media_range': '76,800', 'speed': '2,000'},
 {'header1': '512', 'media_range': '153,600', 'speed': '2,000'},
 {'header1': '243,6', 'media_range': '160,000', 'speed': '2,000'}]
```

Comment: what is IIUC? 

Comment: @uingtea if I understand correctly. It's the laziest way to prefix an answer to make it not code only.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly shorter solution with `zip` and unpacking:

```
temp = [['header1', '4', '8', '16', '32', '64', '128', '256', '512', '243,6'], ['media_range', '1,200', '2,400', '4,800', '4,800', '6,200', '38,400', '76,800', '153,600', '160,000'], ['speed', '300', '600', '1,200', '2,000', '2,000', '2,000', '2,000', '2,000', '2,000']]
header, *data = zip(*temp)
result = [dict(zip(header, i)) for i in data]
```

Output:

```
[{'header1': '4', 'media_range': '1,200', 'speed': '300'}, {'header1': '8', 'media_range': '2,400', 'speed': '600'}, {'header1': '16', 'media_range': '4,800', 'speed': '1,200'}, {'header1': '32', 'media_range': '4,800', 'speed': '2,000'}, {'header1': '64', 'media_range': '6,200', 'speed': '2,000'}, {'header1': '128', 'media_range': '38,400', 'speed': '2,000'}, {'header1': '256', 'media_range': '76,800', 'speed': '2,000'}, {'header1': '512', 'media_range': '153,600', 'speed': '2,000'}, {'header1': '243,6', 'media_range': '160,000', 'speed': '2,000'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use zip(). This requires you to know how many lists but does the expected output.

```py
for header1,media_range,speed in zip(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]):
    if header1 != "header1":
        output.append({temp[0][0]: header1, temp[1][0]: media_range, temp[2][0]: speed})
```

Comment: it does this job but not very scalable